# In an elastic collision, is momentum conserved at every instant and not just before and after?

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Assume two objects with different momentum. The momentum before and after the collision between these two objects is equal but if the collision causes one of the objects to reverse in direction, the velocity of that object at the exact time of collision must be zero. At that instantaneous point in time the momentum is zero.

My professor told me this and asked me how this made sense since momentum should always be equal. Any ideas?

Comment: In the center-of-mass frame the total momentum is always zero. Consider that for a bit, and what it means for other frames.

Comment: m1 * v1i + m2 * v2i = m1 * v1f + m2 * v2f   -- > m1 and m2 are the masses of the two objects
v1i and v2i are the initial velocities of the two objects before the collision
v1f and v2f are the final velocities of the two objects after the collision

Comment: This may help - [Impact force of object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/747613/37364)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Total momentum is always conserved, under all circumstances, at every point in time. The momentum of any given object is not necessarily conserved. Indeed, it is unlikely to be so when forces are acting.

If you find a time at which all the objects in your system have zero momentum, then total momentum is zero. That means you are in the center-of-momentum reference frame. The definition of the COM frame is the frame in which total momentum is zero.

Comment: “Total momentum is always conserved”. Think it should say “total momentum of an isolated system”

Answer (score 0):

A thought experiment taken to its logical extreme may be helpful.  Consider object $m_1$ moving on a frictionless horizontal surface at velocity $v_1$.  This object has a massless spring attached to it.  Object $m_1$ strikes stationary object $m_2$ with its spring "head on", and object $m_2$ is twice the mass of object $m_1$.  During the collision, the spring will compress, and the forces associated with that compression will store potential energy in the spring, slow down $m_1$ and speed up $m_2$.  At some point in this collision, $m_1$ will come to rest while there is still potential energy stored in the spring.  As the collision continues, that spring potential energy will push both objects (due to Newton's 3rd law) until the objects separate, at which time, object $m_1$ will reverse direction while object $m_2$ will move "forward".  At that point, a calculation will indicate that momentum was conserved.  If the momentum calculation is done at the instant that $m_1$ is at rest, momentum will not be conserved, but the collision has not concluded at that point, so it is premature to try to conserve momentum during the collision.

This thought experiment is extensible to other objects that experience an elastic collision.  For example, the steel balls of Newton's cradle act like objects that have tiny, very stiff springs attached to them, with the spring constant being related to Young's modulus.  Due to that extreme "spring stiffness", the time interval during which the collision occurs is VERY brief, but there is no doubt that during the few microseconds that the collision is occurring, there will be some storage of potential energy in the steel balls of that system that lead to the same kind of interaction noted above.